# Where is the safest place to build a colony on the Moon?

Tags: moons, space-constructs, colonies, space-colonization

I'm working on a universe which implies that humanity settled on the Moon.

Knowing that we want to keep contact with the Earth (means we don't want to settle on the hidden face) and we want to avoid the facilities to be destroyed systematically by the asteroid falling on the moon, what place on the Moon humanity should have picked in order to build the safest colony possible?

Comment: Asteroid impacts on the Moon are really, really, really, really, really, really unlikely.

Comment: Really? But if it is so, why is the moon completely covered with impacts holes?

Comment: Those are from meteorites, not asteroids. Also, many formed during the Late Heavy Bombardment, a long time ago.

Comment: I think I meant meteorite... Sorry.
So one could be safely walking around or building things on the moon without fearing his facilities being destroyed by falling debris from the space?

Comment: Judging from some basic data given http://history.nasa.gov/SP-467/ch3.htm - which could be out of date - I'd say that he should be okay.

Comment: Hi, I rolled back your edit - it's a good question but invalidates all the answers to this question. In other words it is a new question and should be asked as a new question :)

Comment: Ok I thought so but I wasn't sure. I'll ask a new question then.

Comment: I would say that if we have enough resources to build a moonbase, we would have enough resources to keep it in contact with earth even if it was on the far side of the moon. Its basically trivial at that point to orbit a few comm satellites around the moon, or just hardwire comms to a comm relay on the near side. Dont forget that we can talk to people on the other side of the earth with no problem.

Comment: @HDE226868 I don't know how likely an asteroid strike is on the moon.  A meteorite is far less likely - baring human intervention in a somewhat bizarre experiment I don't see how one could get to the moon.

Comment: I don't know why the outer face of the moon would be so bad.  Communication will likely be bouncing off orbiters and sent to Earth.  I'm not saying it would be better, but I don't think communication is a worry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's been considerable effort at looking to build a lunar base. [This](http://www.space.com/957-perfect-spot-moon-base.html) specific bit of research used data obtained from [Clementine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clementine_(spacecraft)) to determine that a likely place to build a lunar base was on the rim of the [Peary crater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peary_(crater)). This would give the base access to what is believed to be frozen water sources at the north pole and provide a respectable amount of sunlight for constant solar power and relatively stable temperature.

Answer (score 3):

#### Near the poles

Unless you plan on having artificial light for your greenhouses, then the 14-day nights are going to murder what you plant. Wherever you put it, go underground. The excavation of ice from under the surface would lend itself to this.

As would the constant, unshielded bombardment of cosmic radiation upon the surface. Any surface facilities are likely to be limited to the conductive element of a communication array, and the launch/reception pad.

I have a planetary geology textbook published in the '70's and it likens dust on the moon's surface as a sort of naturally occurring unmixed concrete. So, to limit the amount of materials you'll use what's already at hand.

I'd envision concrete-lined tunnels, which tend to follow whatever sort of factors influence subterranean ice flow.

Comment: "Any surface facilities are likely to be limited to the conductive element of a communication array" Possibly you should add solar panels to this.  Also if everything is underground your greenhouse is going to use artificial lights, so your first couple of sentences seems weird.

Comment: I don't understand the 14-day nights?

Comment: @Mikey 14-day days and 14-day nights.  On the Moon, you'll see one sunrise and one sunset per 28 Earth days because of the Moon being tidally locked with Earth.

Comment: @Brian - Oh jeez, yes, of course, my stupid brain was thinking "well, the moon goes around the Earth every day" (to be fair, I'd had a glass of wine or seven)

Comment: @Mikey LOL, no problem.  Sounds like you had a pretty good night! :D